# is it possible to discard records in kafka connect value converter (de-serialization)?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a custom binary format of my messages in Kafka (protobuf) and I want to avoid processing time when doing the de-serialization of said messages.

My idea would be to somehow discard the messages I do not want during the value converter for de-serialization.

I'm trying to generate a custom value converter that would only process certain messages based on some headers, and I would like to avoid the processing time of deserializing all of the messages.

Up to now I have a sort of filter transformation to discard those messages, but I wanted to avoid even processing them so really discard them on the value converter itself. The transformation if I understood correctly always happens after the converters.

I tried to just return a null on it but that failed, meaning the consumer crashed because the message becomes null. I was wondering if there is a way of doing this and if yes any known example?

If not, I can off-course just return an empty SchemaAndValue but I was wondering if there was a nicer way because this way, I still need to return something and then filter them out with a transformation.

EDIT: Based on the answer, which is what I was looking for the easier way is to simply return the ByteArrayConverter for the messages I'm not interested in

Comment: "but that failed" where?

Comment: I mean the downstream process would fail because kafka would not know how to handle a null value. I got a null pointer exception further down the line. anyway, I'll edit the question with your feedback because the answer you gave is what I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering is a type of processing, so a transform is the correct way to do this.

If you meant you want to prevent deserialization, and you're using some custom binary format and filtering based on its content, maybe using record headers would be a better way to exclude events instead. Then use ByteArrayConverter as a pass-through

Comment: this is exactly what I meant, I wanted to discard, or avoid de-serializing the messages that I have for my custom binary code (protobuf)